# JQuery Validation & realperson Captcha Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form & am using jquery realperson for the captcha. The problem is the hash for the realperson field is not getting submitted.  I want to validate the form including captcha and return the result on the same page whether successful or not.

Here is my example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Real Person</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.realperson.css">
<style>
label { display: inline-block; width: 20%; }
.realperson-challenge { display: inline-block }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.realperson.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="form-validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#defaultReal').realperson();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form action="formProcess.php" method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm">
<p><label>Other fields:</label><input type="text" id="field" name="field"></p>
<p><label>Please enter the letters displayed:</label>
    <input type="text" id="defaultReal" name="defaultReal"></p>
<p style="clear: both;"><label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
<div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my custom form submit:

```
    $.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
            //form validation rules
            $("#myForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    field: "required"
                    },
                messages: {
                    field: "Please enter something"
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                $("#result").html('');
                postForm();
             }

            });

function postForm() {
    var ajaxRequest;
    $("#result").html('');
    var values = $("#myForm").serialize()
    ajaxRequest= $.ajax({
            url: "formProcess.php",
            type: "post",
            data: values
        });

     ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          // show successfully for submit message
          $("#result").html(response);
     });

     /* On failure of request this function will be called  */
     ajaxRequest.fail(function (){
       // show error
       $("#result").html('There was an error!');
     });

    }


});
```

And my php processForm:

```
    <?php
function rpHash($value) {
    $hash = 5381;
    $value = strtoupper($value);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
        $hash = (leftShift32($hash, 5) + $hash) + ord(substr($value, $i));
    }
    return $hash; }

function leftShift32($number, $steps) {
    $binary = decbin($number);
    $binary = str_pad($binary, 32, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $binary = $binary.str_repeat("0", $steps);
    $binary = substr($binary, strlen($binary) - 32);
    return ($binary{0} == "0" ? bindec($binary) :
        -(pow(2, 31) - bindec(substr($binary, 1)))); 
}

if (rpHash($_POST['defaultReal']) == $_POST['defaultRealHash']) {

    echo "Security was Correct!";
}
else {
    echo "Security captcha incorrect!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Dump your $_POST in PHP and see your what you get back in your XHR object in your Firebug or Chrome dev tools or ....

Comment: Yes I have done that and defaultRealHash is not in the form data. It is a hidden field that is attached to the form by the realperson jquery. It's something to do with the way the jquery is submitting the form.  If I use form.submit()  instead it works but then I get no response back and the page changes to the formProcess.php

Comment: Yea, I read the person script last night and I see now that you are overriding the submit behavior with validate etc. When you say form.submit() works? Where did you put it? You put it inside your postForm() and removes the AJAX? You need to make sure that the realperson plugin sets the fields before submitting the form.

Comment: I am also not getting value in post..if anyone got solution then please update here